# hierarchical fulltext search in neo4j

Tags: search, neo4j, full-text-search, cypher

I have parent/child graph in neo4j: decision(parent, list of child decision) which have property name (string) I'm going to use for search. it perfectly find my decisions which have search term in name by query:

```
START d=node:node_auto_index({autoIndexQuery}) MATCH (d:Decision) RETURN d
```

I want to complicate this query to find decision which have search term in name AND ALSO have search term in names of its children:

```
Name of relation is CONTAINS (Decision CONTAINS decisions)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following query should work:

```
START parent=node:node_auto_index({autoIndexQuery}) 
WITH parent
START child=node:node_auto_index({autoIndexQuery}) 
MATCH (parent:Decision)-[:contains]->(child:Decision) 
where parent <> child
RETURN parent, child;
```

One issue here is that a full text query condition (I *think*) can only take place in a `START` block.  This means you'd need to match both parent and child that way, then connect them with `MATCH`.

This might take some time to complete, depending on how many nodes you have matching, since the query will mostly see if this parent/child relationship exists between all of the nodes that match.  But it should get the job done.

Comment: this query does not return results :(

Comment: Is there something specific that's wrong with the query that you didn't mean?  Just because it doesn't return results doesn't mean it's wrong.  Maybe there's nothing in your database that suits those criteria.

Comment: nope, db is ok, probably i have missed right term is declaration of reqiurement AND ALSO must be OR ALSO

Comment: it depends how many children you have, it either might make sense to only use the index for the parent and then check the children with a regexp-match or the other way round.